# Conditionally yield a generator in python

Tags: python, yield

Let's say I have this code:

```
def f(data, all_at_once):
    if all_at_once:
        return data
    else:
        yield from data

f([1,2,3], True)
```

`f` always returns a generator, regardless of the value of `all_at_once`. How can I get a function that conditionally returns a generator?

Comment: Change `yield from data` to `return iter(data)`.

Comment: The presence of `yield` as a construct turns the function into a generator of sorts.

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately I want yield objects from a Queue object, that doesn't have an `iter` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. Perhaps it can be improved by a `lambda`

```
def gen(data):
    yield from data

def f(data, all_at_once):
    if all_at_once:
        return data
    return gen(data)

f([1,2,3], True)
```